# How to plot linear regression with Seaborn based on a prediction of a target variable?

Tags: python, regression, seaborn, linear-regression, regplot

I'm learning the very basics of data science and started with regression analysis. So I decided building a linear regression model to examine the linear relationship between two variables (`chemical_1` and `chemical_2`) from this [dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Coil+1999+Competition+Data).

I made `chemical_1` the predictor (independent variable) and `chemical_2` the target (dependent variable). Then used `scipy.stats.linregress` to calculate a regression line.

```
from scipy import stats

X = df['chemical_1']
Y = df['chemical_2']

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, slope_std_error = stats.linregress(X,Y)
predict_y = slope * X + intercept
```

I figured out how to plot the regression line with matplotlib.

```
plt.plot(X, Y, 'o')
plt.plot(X, predict_y)
plt.show()
```

However I want to plot regression with Seaborn. The only option I have discovered for now is the following:

```
sns.set(color_codes=True)
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(7, 7)})
sns.regplot(x=X, y=Y);
```

Is there a way to provide Seaborn with the regression line `predict_y = slope * X + intercept` in order to build a regression plot?

**UPD:** When using the following solution, proposed by RPyStats the Y-axis gets the `chemical_1` name although it should be `chemical_2`.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.set(color_codes=True)
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(8, 8)})
ax = sns.regplot(x=X, y=Y, line_kws={'label':'$y=%3.7s*x+%3.7s$'%(slope, intercept)});
ax.legend()
sns.regplot(x=X, y=Y, fit_reg=False, ax=ax);
sns.regplot(x=X, y=predict_y,scatter=False, ax=ax);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using subplots and setting the axes will allow you to overlay your predicted Y values. Does this answer your question?

```
print(predict_y.name)
predict_y = predict_y.rename('chemical_2')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.set(color_codes=True)
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(7, 7)})
sns.regplot(x=X, y=Y, fit_reg=False, ax=ax,scatter_kws={"color": "green"});
sns.regplot(x=X, y=predict_y,scatter=False, ax=ax, scatter_kws={"color": "green"});
```

Comment: Updated my question, could you take a look at it? Also could you tell why the plot has different colors, not just blue as usual? Is it because of overlaying?

Comment: Your correct in that overlaying the plots will produce different colors, pass in additional arguments to sns.regplot can set them to be the same color. Y-axis name is getting overwritten with the second call to sns.regplot. It says 'chemical_1' as this is the name of the series predict_y. I can update my solution above.

Comment: Got it, thanks! One more question: do you think I've added the legend correctly? It looks as expected but I wonder - is it the most optimal way or could it be improved?

Comment: Your last question is where it gets subjective, if your happy with it and it is working as expected then it's probably safe to keep it as is. Also, I haven't done much research on adding legends to seaborn plots.